# How to use older solc compilers with Truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am trying to reproduce the DAO attack that happened on Ethereum, however, I was not able to compile the DAO code. The current stable version of truffle does not support specifying a solc version.
I used the 5.0.0 beta 1 version for truffle, which supports specifying a solc version. 
When compiling the DAO code, I get this error.

```
TypeError: Error parsing E:/Desktop/MetaCoin/contracts/DAO.sol: solc.compileStandard is not a function
    at Object.parseImports (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\parser.js:49:1)
    at Object.getImports (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:332:1)
    at Promise.all.then.results (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:305:1)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Truffle 5.0.0 beta -0, you can [specify a solcjs version](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0#specify-a-solcjs-version).

I have just tried it in my project and it works. Be sure to make the version number a `string` and use the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ... etc ...
  },
  compilers: {
     solc: {
       version: <string>  // ex:  "0.4.20". (Default: Truffle's installed solc)
     }
  }
};
```